# Use Swift extensions in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is it possible to use Swift extensions in Obj-C?

I'm extending the `UIView` class with some fade animation like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func fadeOut(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I unsuccessfully tried to call it in my Obj-C class like

```
[someView fadeOut(1.0)]
```

Comment: Did it give you a compiler error or a runtime error? what error does it give? Try replacing `UIView.animateWithDuration` with `self.animateWithDuration` where self is referring to the UIView which you are expanding upon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func fadeOut(duration: NSTimeInterval)
```

maps to Objective-C as

```
- (void)fadeOut:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

and is therefore called as

```
[someView fadeOut:1.0];
```

Comment: Duh! Using both languages at once is messing with my head.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work  (where I dragged a Swift extension into an objective-c project). Do you need to import the extension into the objective-c class that uses it, and if so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: @rdelmar: Did you `#import "<#YourProjectName#>-Swift.h"` in the Objective-C file? Compare "Importing Swift into Objective-C" in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html  or "Using Swift Classes in Objective-C" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/1187415.

Comment: I thought I had tried that one, but I guess I didn't. Thanks, that worked.